# JSON parsing in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, highcharts

I have created this snippet here which works with static data :

```js
Highcharts.chart("container", {
  title: {
    text: "Highcharts pie chart"
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Aug",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec"
    ]
  },

  series: [
    {
      type: "pie",
      allowPointSelect: true,
      keys: ["name", "y", "selected", "sliced"],
      data: [
        ["January", 105],
        ["February", 400],
        ["March",230]
      ],
      showInLegend: true
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
@import "https://code.highcharts.com/5/css/highcharts.css";
.highcharts-series .highcharts-point-select {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #f00;
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Now I am trying to parse the data from a JSON query. The JSON has the following format :

```
{"headers":["Month","Clicks"],"rows":[["January",105],["February",400],["March",230]]}
```

So, at the moment the JSON format in the snippet that works is :

```
["January", 105],
["February", 400],
["March",230]
```

I tried using a solution used in examples that worked. In this case, I cannot parse the data correctly. In the new snippet below, I added a JS script in the beginning of the JS box to parse the JSON data.

```js
var unformatted = {"headers":["Month","impressions"],"rows":[["January",124010],["February",545010]]};

var data2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < unformatted.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = unformatted.rows[i];
    
    data2.push({
        Month: row[0],
        Clicks: row[1]
    });
}

Highcharts.chart("container", {
  title: {
    text: "Clicks per Month"
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Aug",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec"
    ]
  },

  series: [
    {
      type: "pie",
      allowPointSelect: true,
      keys: ["name", "y", "selected", "sliced"],
      data: data2
      ,
      showInLegend: true
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
@import "https://code.highcharts.com/5/css/highcharts.css";
.highcharts-series .highcharts-point-select {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #f00;
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the first row, then grab the data from each item in that array.

```
categories: unformatted.rows[0].map(record => record[0])
```

The data is just the rows.

```
data: unformatted.rows
```

```js
// Return unique array of items.
const unique = list => [...new Set(list)];

var unformatted = {
  "headers": ["Month", "impressions"],
  "rows": [
    ["January", 124010],
    ["February", 545010]
  ]
};

Highcharts.chart("container", {
  title: {
    text: "Clicks per Month"
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: unique(unformatted.rows[0].map(record => record[0]))
  },
  series: [{
    type: "pie",
    allowPointSelect: true,
    keys: ["name", "y", "selected", "sliced"],
    data: unformatted.rows,
    showInLegend: true
  }]
});
```

```css
@import "https://code.highcharts.com/5/css/highcharts.css";
.highcharts-series .highcharts-point-select {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #f00;
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `"rows"` contains your data why not not just make your `series.data` be the `"rows"` element and not loop through the JSON. So you would have this:

```
var unformatted = {"headers":["Month","impressions"],"rows":[["January",124010],["February",545010]]};

var data2 = [];
//console.log(unformatted.rows);
data2 = unformatted.rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was with **data2.push** part

```
// instead
data2.push({
    Month: row[0],
    Clicks: row[1]
});

//you should do 
data2.push([row[0], row[1]]);
```

Here is the fixed version of **your code**

```js
var unformatted = {"headers":["Month","impressions"],"rows":[["January",124010],["February",545010]]};

var data2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < unformatted.rows.length; i++) {
    var row = unformatted.rows[i];
    
    data2.push([row[0], row[1]]);

}

Highcharts.chart("container", {
  title: {
    text: "Clicks per Month"
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Aug",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec"
    ]
  },

  series: [
    {
      type: "pie",
      allowPointSelect: true,
      keys: ["name", "y", "selected", "sliced"],
      data: data2,
      showInLegend: true
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
@import "https://code.highcharts.com/5/css/highcharts.css";
.highcharts-series .highcharts-point-select {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: #f00;
  stroke-dasharray: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/5/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```